# JPA Query or Custom Query to Find Results Based on Search Term in Two Tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, thymeleaf

Im trying to build an extensive search that returns the results from multiple tables. I don't know if I worded that correctly, but I want to be able to return all posts that match a search criteria that search the post title and body (table 1), tags/categories (table 2) and comments (table 3).

The closest thing I've semi-gotten to work was this custom query:

```
@(value = "select p.*, cat.category, c.body from posts as p join categories as cat join comments as c where p.title like %?1% or p.body like %?2% or cat.category like %?3% or c.body like %?4%", nativeQuery = true)
```

But this tends to give me duplicate entries. I've even only selected `p.*` along with the join, and still not returning what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `distinct` keyword `"select distinct p.*, xxxxxxx"`

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply. This partially worked for me. It seems that it would only display posts where comments had been made even though I have a "OR" condition

Comment: Can you add more details on how the classes look and how they are linked (`@OneToMany`, `@ManyToMany`, ...)?

Comment: Posts being the main one connects to the comments via a post_id, as well does the tags -- both @OneToMany. Now, I do have sub-comment which are tied to comment_id, but I figured since the first set of comments are tied to the post, it would all connect, right?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! I can't believe I missed this. Instead of it being an inner join, I needed to changed all joins to left to return null records as well.

So final, workable query looks like the following:

```
@(value = "select p.*, cat.category, c.body from posts as p left join categories as cat left join comments as c where p.title like %?1% or p.body like %?2% or cat.category like %?3% or c.body like %?4%", nativeQuery = true)
```